# ASP.NET:,Will session variables exist when Application_Error method being called from global.asax?

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

In ASP.NET ,Will session variables exist when Application_Error method being called from global.asax ?Can i access values of my session variables there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on whether or not the error occurs before or after the AcquireRequestState event is raised.  This is the point in which the Session can be identified for a given request.